# trying to pass result of sequelize query to pug

Tags: node.js, pug, sequelize.js

I am trying to pass search result of a sequelize query to pug, but its not working

```
res.render('search',{
    stack_holder:find_stack_holder(),
});
function find_stack_holder(){
    return db.poregister.findAll({
        attributes: [[Sequelize.fn('DISTINCT', Sequelize.col('stack_holder')), 'stack_holder']],
    })
}
```

However pug gets promise instead of actual data. Aren't promises supposed to resolve themselves when the actual data are needed?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findAll` returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), so, you need to do something like this:

```
const findAllPromise = find_stack_holder();

findAllPromise.then(function(result) {
    res.render('search',{
        stack_holder: result,
    });
});

function find_stack_holder() {
    return db.poregister.findAll({
        attributes: [[Sequelize.fn('DISTINCT', Sequelize.col('stack_holder')), 'stack_holder']],
    });
}
```

Comment: I do realize that, i had multiple promises so I used promise.all(arr). But from what i understood, aren't promises supposed to be resolved when the data is actually needed?